# Positive Derivative

Tags: tag-removed, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Let $\;f : \; \stackrel{\circ}{D}\; \subset \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ differentiable in $x_0 \in \; \stackrel{\circ}{D}\;$ and $f\;'(x_0) > 0$.

Does exists a neighborhood $A \subset \; \stackrel{\circ}{D}\;$ of $x_0$ where $f$ is crescent?

Comment: Does crescent mean increasing?

Comment: I think it's a translation from something that means "waxing" (like the moon, or "waning" I can never remember which is which).



Comment: According to Wikipedia, *the word "crescent" itself, derived from the Latin verb crescere "to grow", literally means "waxing" or "increasing", and was originally applied to the form of the waxing moon (luna crescens).*

Comment: "Croissant" has the obvious dual sense in French (AFAIK) so I wouldn't be surprised to see this in other, related languages

Comment: Crescendo... $   $

Answer (score 5):

No. The function
$$f(x)= x+2x^2\sin\frac{1}{x},\quad x\in\mathbb R,$$
is not monotonic in any neighborhood of $x=0$ yet $f'(0)=1$.

Comment: You just beat me. I would like to comment that f' is not continuous at 0. If we add the condition that f' be continuous at x_0, then f is increasing in an interval around x_0.

Comment: Right, because then $f'$ is necessarily positive on an entire interval, not just at the point.  Even in freshman calculus I try to make the distinction between "pointwise positivity" of $f'$ implies $f$ is increasing "through" the point -- i.e., smaller to the left, bigger to the right -- whereas "intervalwise positivity" implies increasing on an interval.  I assumed this was part of the standard spiel.  Now I wonder whether I am being too ambitious...